# Angular $routeProvider - Nested controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I Have an Angular app, that currently uses `$routeProvider` to map a route to a controller and template.

Some of the routes render collections of items, and at the moment it simply includes another template for each item, accessing the controller of the parent template.

main route template...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.collection">
   <div ng-include="'/views/item.html'"></div>
</div>
```

However, as this app is growing, it feels like the include, the item view, should have its own controller, separate to the collection controller, allowing it be reused more easily throughout the app.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have functionality that can be thought of as a **Component**, you should use **Services** (if it doesn't have a UI) or directives (if it does have a UI).

If the functionality you wan't to separate is not that generic to implement as a reusable component, you could create a **Controller** and use it with the `ng-controller` directive.

Another way to use the controller is to switch to **UI-Router**, which allows nested views.